Deploying machine learning flask api (h5 models)
I have a model that predicts the co2 emission in the next 30 years,and i need to deploy it as an api to retrieve the prediction data as json from a visualisation web project but the problem when using pythonanywhere is it can't acces the h5 models files from although they're in the same directory.
i tried another approches to acces the models but it stays the same :
this is the api flask code :
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
from prophet import Prophet
import joblib
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

loaded_model_arima = joblib.load('model_arima.h5')
loaded_model_holt = joblib.load('model_holt.h5')
loaded_model_prophet = joblib.load('model_prophet.h5')

@app.route('/ARIMA', methods=['GET'])
def predict_arima():
    years = int(30)
    forecast = loaded_model_arima.forecast(steps=years)
    forecast_index = [str(2022 + i) for i in range(1, years + 1)]
    return jsonify({'annee': forecast_index, 'prediction': forecast.tolist()})

@app.route('/HOLT-WINTERS', methods=['GET'])
def predict_holt_winters():
    years = int(30)
    forecast = loaded_model_holt.forecast(steps=years)
    forecast_index = [str(2022 + i) for i in range(1, years + 1)]
    return jsonify({'annee': forecast_index, 'prediction': forecast.tolist()})

@app.route('/prophet', methods=['GET'])
def predict_prophet():
    years = int(request.json['years'])
    future = pd.DataFrame({'ds': pd.date_range(start='2023-01-01', periods=years, freq='A')})
    forecast = loaded_model_prophet.predict(future)
    forecast_data = forecast[['ds', 'yhat']]
    forecast_index = [str(date.year) for date in forecast_data['ds']]
    forecast_values = forecast_data['yhat'].tolist()
    return jsonify({'annee': forecast_index, 'prediction': forecast_values})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)

this is the error i get :
2024-04-30 17:43:57,222: Error running WSGI application
2024-04-30 17:43:57,222: KeyError: 92
2024-04-30 17:43:57,222:   File "/var/www/wildvcwduibv_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2024-04-30 17:43:57,222:     from flask_app import app as application  # noqa
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223: 
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223:   File "/home/wildvcwduibv/mysite/flask_app.py", line 11, in <module>
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223:     loaded_model_arima = joblib.load('/home/wildvcwduibv/mysite/model_arima.h5')
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223: 
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 587, in load
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223:     obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223: 
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 506, in _unpickle
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223:     obj = unpickler.load()
2024-04-30 17:43:57,223: 
2024-04-30 17:43:57,224:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 1213, in load
2024-04-30 17:43:57,224:     dispatch[key[0]](self)
2024-04-30 17:43:57,224: ***************************************************
2024-04-30 17:43:57,224: If you're seeing an import error and don't know why,
2024-04-30 17:43:57,224: we have a dedicated help page to help you debug: 
2024-04-30 17:43:57,224: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DebuggingImportError/
2024-04-30 17:43:57,224: ***************************************************

i tried different libraries like h5py to acces the h5 models butnothing worked, i also tried a diferent deploying services ,got the same problems or dependencies problems
